# Добавление данных с форму в mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Итак, проблема следующая: у меня есть 2 страницы с формами, чтобы добавить данные в mysql. Данные прекрасно добавляются, но дело в следующем: на 1-ой странице у меня указана обработчиком 2-ая страница (название inpuе = 'next-page'). На 2-ой странице обработчиком указана тоже 2-ая страница (название input = 'end-page'). И если я напишу следующий код, то данные добавятся только с 1-ой страницы:

```
                `if(isset($_POST['next-page'])){
                $animal = strip_tags(trim($_POST['animal']));
                $category = strip_tags(trim($_POST['category']));
                $description = strip_tags(trim($_POST['description']));
                $telephone = strip_tags(trim($_POST['telephone']));
                // 2-ая страница
                $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST['name']));
                $signs = strip_tags(trim($_POST['signs']));
                $breed = strip_tags(trim($_POST['breed']));
                $color = strip_tags(trim($_POST['color']));
                mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO advert (missing, categorie_id, text, telephone, name, signs, breed, color) VALUES ('$animal', '$category', '$description', '$telephone', '$name', '$signs', '$breed', '$color')") or die(mysqli_error($connection));
    }`
```

Если поменять 'next-page' на 'end-page', то данные добавятся со 2-ой страницы. Мне нужно, чтобы всё добавилось вместе

Comment: А так нельзя `if(isset($_POST['next-page']) || isset($_POST[end-page]))` либо `if(isset($_POST['next-page']) or isset($_POST[end-page]))`? Хотя не совсем понятно, зачем один обработчик на две страницы...

Comment: А как бы вы сделали?